# Getting Error in SMS integration Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have integrated SMS sending code to my website to sending message to a particular user.After integrating sms code, it's sending message successfully but an error is shown in client server

```
 Failed : Mobile number value is missing Success: Message id: *************
```

I am totally confused with this coz it doesn't happen on localhost but displaying on client server.

I have edited my code here :-

```
    $message2 = "Dear " . $this->input->post('patient_name') . ".your appointment (" . $docdata->id . ") with Dr." . $docdata->f_name . " " . $docdata->l_name . " has been confirmed at " . $docdata->location . " ," . date('h:i A', strtotime($this->input->post('appoitment_time'))) . "," . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($this->input->post('appointment_date'))) . ".For any help";
    $subject ="MyWebsite";
    $content = "Dear " . $this->input->post('name') .",<br />". "your appointment (" . $docdata->id . ") with Dr." . $docdata->f_name . " " . $docdata->l_name . " has been confirmed at "."-<br />". $docdata->location . " ," . date('h:i A', strtotime($this->input->post('appoitment_time'))) . "," . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($this->input->post('appointment_date'))) .".<br />"."For any help";

    $user_id = 'Website'; // Your Username
    $pwd = '**********';    // Your Password
    $sender_id = 'ABCDE';  // Add 6 char sender id viz: HDFCBK
    $mobile_num = $this->input->post('phone');  // Mobile Number, You can add comma separated mobile number
    $email_id = $this->input->post('email');  // Email Address, You can add comma separated email id
    $this->sendMail($this->input->post('email'), $subject,$content,"abc@gmail.com");

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://tra.bulksmshyderabad.co.in/websms/sendsms.aspx?userid=" . $user_id . "&password=" . $pwd . "&sender=" . $sender_id . "&mobileno=" . urlencode($mobile_num) . "&msg=" . urlencode($message2));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Please Check it..

Can anyone help to get this.Where m going wrong.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: which library using for sending sms? share code and other details

Comment: post your code,

Comment: Without checking your code no one will tell you what is the issue

Comment: Please check my edited code  @user7234862

Comment: do check docs if you need to urlencode() the mobile number?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my instance right now to test this but you can try below code.

```
$curl = curl_init();
$strMessage  = urlencode(" Write Your message here ");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://your url with parameters(like $strMessage)");  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```